# What are rationalizing factors?

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers, square-numbers, number-systems

I don't know what rationalizing factors are and I need help finding $\sqrt[5]{a^2b^3c^4}$

There are some options

A) $\sqrt[5]{a^3b^2c}$

B) $\sqrt[4]{a^3b^2c}$

C) $\sqrt[3]{a^3b^2c}$

D) $\sqrt{a^3b^2c}$

Comment: What would you do with those "rationalizing factors", if you knew what they are and you had them?

Comment: https://www.math-only-math.com/rationalization-of-surds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt[5]{a^2b^3c^4}.\sqrt[5]{a^3b^2c}=  \sqrt[5]{a^5b^5c^5}=abc.$

Therefore (A) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can't rationalize the polynomial $a^2b^3c^4$ because the fifth-root isn't further simplyficable.